# How do I get 7 random elements from an array which was converted to a list?

Tags: java, arrays, list, random

```
public static String doDraw(String cardName[], int deckSize){
    int counter, n;
    String list;

    List<Cin> cardList = Arrays.asList(cardName);
Collections.shuffle(cardList);
    ? cardList = cardList.get(7);

    System.out.println(cardList);
}
```

So I cannot seem to get the right way of getting code for the random. The program takes a deck of cards and draws 7 random cards to simulate a first hand draw. I have made the array into a list and have shuffled it. I just am not 100% sure on where to go with getting the 7 random cards now.

Comment: Have you read the javadoc for List?

Comment: That should be your first step.

Answer (score 0):

use `for` loop and print first/last 7 items from shuffled list...

Answer (score 0):

After shuffling use cardList.subList(0, 7)

ArrayList's get(index) returns only one element at mentioned index. If you need 7 use subList(). If you want only one you need not shuffle.. Use random

```
java.util.Random random = new Random();
cardList.get(random.nextInt(cardList.size()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either a for or while loop and print the items, you can also use an enhanced for loop

```
for(int variable : cardList)
{
  System.out.print(variable + "\t");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After shuffling the element in the List. You have to either print them or create a string of first few elements. I am creating the string of first 7 elements in the list but you are free to access the list either from begning or from the end.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class CardShuffle {
    String cardName[] = {"first", "second", "third", "forth", "sixth",
            "seventh", "eight", "ninth", "tenth", "eleventh"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CardShuffle card = new CardShuffle();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(doDraw(card.cardName, 7));
        }
    }

    public static String doDraw(String cardName[], int length) {
        List<String> cardList = Arrays.asList(cardName);
        Collections.shuffle(cardList);
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result = result.append(cardList.get(i) + " ");
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```